# When will visitors see AMP version of an article?

Tags: html, wordpress, amp-html

First of all, I'm trying AMP for the first time and I don't have enough knowledge about it. And I installed [AMP for WordPress](https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp) plugin, and it seems everything is setup successfully. The articles on my site are now having a link tag with the value of `amphtml` for `rel` attribute.

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://example.com/link-to-amp-version-of-article/amp/">
```

And a canonical url on the amp version of articles

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/link-to-original-version-of-article/">
```

Now visiting that amp version of post url works. But, when I search on google for any of my site's article, clicking them doesn't take me to the AMP version of url. Wasn't that should be? (*please enlighten me if I'm wrong*). [Validation of amp](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/validate.html) urls is giving no errors. What am I missing?

Comment: Do you used Google with a Mobil device? On my site it was about two days delay before Google send me visitors. Without sitemap or something else.

Comment: And do you have check the search console (webmaster tools) for errors and indexed?

Comment: Still no error found, but I have seen some of my amp pages are indexed, not all. @Lovntola

Answer (score 1):

As today, Google is using AMPs for the AMP-based news carousel in Mobile Search and Google News:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/webmasters/gECaJ0KGxgQ/c3NhRn41CQAJ

Other platforms are also displaying AMP versions of news articles when available:
https://blog.twitter.com/2016/explore-links-in-moments-1

Comment: And google send me ~60% (analytics) of mobil user (mobil & tablet) to the AMP sites.